# Sum Multiple Rows But Retain the Number of Rows in a Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my SQL Server 2008 stored procedure, I have a table variable with `RecordID`, `TotalMinutes`, `ProcessID`.

```
Declare @tblSum table(RecordID int, TotalMinutes int, ProcessID int)
```

RecordID is my primary key, total minutes is the total minutes, and I have different processes but these processes are repeated multiple times on my data.

Here is an example of my data:

```
  RecordID     TotalMinutes     ProcessID 
 --------------------------------------------
   1              10            1        
   2              20            1       
   3              30            1
   4              10            2       
   5              40            2
   6              10            2
   7              10            3        
   8              55            3       
   9              60            3       
   10             15            4
```

My plan is to return the data by totaling or adding all the data with same ProcessID and put it on a new table variable with `FinalMinutes` column just like the table below:

```
RecordID     TotalMinutes     ProcessID     FinalMinutes
 -----------------------------------------------------
   1              10            1           60
   2              20            1           60
   3              30            1           60
   4              10            2           80
   5              60            2           80
   6              10            2           80
   7              10            3           125
   8              55            3           125
   9              60            3           125
   10             15            4           15
```

I cannot do a group by since it will cut the result into 4 rows. I need to retain the number of rows, and every data it has, I will just add a `FinalMinutes` column on a new table variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `SUM()Over()` windowed aggregate function

```
Select *,
       FinalMinutes = sum(TotalMinutes)over(partition by ProcessID)
From yourtable
```